# ArrayList ignore null value causing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I trying to get a specific data from a line that using ! as split.
For example:

```
S!ARC!256!547291!840.50!9038.00!840.50!9038.00!519.50!9038.00!321.00!0.00!COUNTERCLOCKWISE!ASSEMBLY_TOP!BAT-2-CR1632-T0_R!BT2K!
```

so when i split the line using ! and put it in array, the array should contain 16 data. But i facing problem that when data like

```
S!LINE!257!37825 1!3525.00!10720.00!4525.00!10720.00!6.00!!!!!ASSEMBLY_TOP!CSCO-LABEL-ASY-73-SN-COMB_R!!
```

and it ignore the last data which is null or "". So when i try to take the data[15] , the problem ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException keep pop out.Below are some code that i write:

```
String[] data = $LINE_LIST.get(k).split("!");                     
if ($LINE_LIST.get(k).startsWith("S!") &&  $LINE_LIST.get(k).contains("ASSEMBLY_TOP"))
                    { 

                            $GRAPHIC.append(data[15])
                                .append("!")
                                .append(data[14])
                                .append("!")
                                .append("TOP")
                                .append("\n");
                    }
```

Any way to solve this problem??

Comment: For the first time I'm seeing a variable name starts with $?

Comment: poor formatting. Please improve.

Comment: It was a String builder for $GRAPHIC and $LINE_LIST is a ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

`split` eliminates trailing empty Strings. Therefore, in your example the length of the array would be 15, so `data[15]` is out of bounds.

```
0 "S"
1 "LINE"
2 "257"
3 "37825 1"
4 "3525.00"
5 "10720.00"
6 "4525.00"
7 "10720.00"
8 "6.00"
9 ""
10 ""
11 ""
12 ""
13 "ASSEMBLY_TOP"
14 "CSCO-LABEL-ASY-73-SN-COMB_R"
```

You must check that `data.length > 15` before accessing `data[15]`.

Here's a relevant quote from the Javadoc of `split` :

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Comment: so i should add 1 more condition in my if to look like this?
    
       if ($LINE_LIST.get(k).startsWith("S!") &&  $LINE_LIST.get(k).contains("ASSEMBLY_TOP") && data.length>15)

Comment: @Jian.Eoh You should also make sure that `data[14]` is valid. It is in your sample input, but I don't know if it's valid for any input.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String s="S!LINE!257!37825 1!3525.00!10720.00!4525.00!10720.00!6.00!!!!!ASSEMBLY_TOP!CSCO-LABEL-ASY-73-SN-COMB_R!! ";
        String arr[]=s.split("!"); // split line with delimiter !
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null)); // remove empty entry
        System.out.println(list); // now list contains your desired data
```

Now you can access specific data from a list

```
[S, LINE, 257, 37825 1, 3525.00, 10720.00, 4525.00, 10720.00, 6.00, ASSEMBLY_TOP, CSCO-LABEL-ASY-73-SN-COMB_R,  ]
```